# Passing an input through a function on same page

Tags: php, html

Hello I am attempting to pass input through to a function, but every time I try the page seems to send input but does not output.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['submit']) )
{
$url = htmlentities($_GET['val1']);
getCoinUrl($url);
}

function getCoinUrl($url)
{
    $uuid = "MYUUID#";
    $url = rawurlencode($url);

    $result = file_get_contents("https://coinurl.com/api.php?uuid={$uuid}&url={$url}");

    if($result == 'error')
        return false;
    else
        return $result;
}
?>
```

And here is the html:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
    Long URL:
    <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>
```

I know that the function is working, but what am I doing wrong when I try to submit?

*note: All of this is on the same page.

Comment: Could it be that you want to include an `echo` statement somewhere? Bit hard to guess what you are trying to do, but maybe `echo getCoinUrl($url);` will solve your problem

Comment: give the name of your submit button like `name="submit"`

Comment: Why are you checking if a submit button has a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this

```
$result = file_get_contents("https://coinurl.com/api.php?uuid=".$uuid."&url=".$url);
```

and also change your html code

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
Long URL:
<input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 <input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
```

to

```
 <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
```

You are missing the name of the "submit" button also no need to have

```
</input>
```

(closing tag not required)

Answer (score 1):

Reason for you submit button doesn't have `name` attribute,

In that case you need to add `name="submit"` attribute in your  `submit` button, since you have used the same in your conditon block `if( isset($_GET['submit']) )`

```
    <?php
        if( isset($_GET['submit']) )
        {
        $url = htmlentities($_GET['val1']);
        getCoinUrl($url);
        }

        function getCoinUrl($url)
        {

            echo $_GET['val1']; // you get the value directly into the function as well
            $uuid = "MYUUID#";
            $url = rawurlencode($url);

            $result = file_get_contents("https://coinurl.com/api.php?uuid=".$uuid."&url=".$url);

            if($result == 'error')
                return false;
            else
                return $result;
        }
        ?>

        <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
            Long URL:
            <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
        </form>
```

Comment: i haven't downvote you but i thing you miss the modify the url in `file_get_contents`

Comment: @Satish Sharma, `$result = file_get_contents("https://coinurl.com/api.php?uuid={$uuid}&url={$url}");` this should also work! The main  thing is `name="submit"` attribute not present in his html.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="text" name="val1" id="val1" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="sbumit" />
```

instead of

```
<input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
```

and **PHP**

```
$filename = "https://coinurl.com/api.php?uuid=".$uuid."&url=".$url;
$result = file_get_contents($filename);
```